# Kotlin arrayList - can't rewrite the list

Tags: android, arraylist, collections, kotlin

I am using a class named ItemHolder to hold some objects in a List . Dynamically I add some . At a certain point I need to clear the items(all of them) to add new ones . When I try to get an item from list I get the IndexOutOfBoundException .

Here is the code I use :

Inside ItemHolder

```
    var itemList : ArrayList<Item> = arrayListOf()
```

In another class on init :

```
    itemHolder.itemList = arrayListOf()
```

And later on the same class :

```
itemHolder.itemList.add(position, database.getRandomData())
```

and :

```
itemHolder.getItem(position)
```

The problem is that when I first time use the class it works fine but second time throws me the exception .

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: studio.monk.rq, PID: 2812
                                                                   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                       at studio.monk.rq.common.ItemHolder.getItem(ItemHolder.kt:9)
                                                                       at studio.monk.rq.fragments.MainFragment$onCreateView$vpPageChangeListener$1.onPageSelected(MainFragment.kt:44)
                                                                       at studio.monk.rq.fragments.MainFragment$onCreateView$1.run(MainFragment.kt:51)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Kotlin lists are immutable. Use `mutableListOf`

Comment: @RachitMishra it has nothing to do with that, this is just a standard ArrayList from Java

Comment: Hmm! Yup my bad! Can you post the exception.

Comment: @Rachit Mishra Added. I also checked the logs , the add methode comes before get so idk why it won't add items

Comment: It is about the execution order of your code. It can't be debugged by knowing only a few line of the code.

Comment: @BakaWaii https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749355/viewpager-in-fragment-is-not-working-second-time - here you can find almost all the code , but there I am using ViewPagerAdapter to hold the items and I have the same problem .

Comment: @BakaWaii , it's not about the execution code but the way I want to assign an empty List to a variable I am using . Otherwise it wouldn't work on first launch .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define a new list using arrayListOf.

Use `ArrayList()` since `arrayListOf()` is only used if you want to intialize a list using existing values and set the size of the items you provide. In your case it intialize a List with the size of 0.

That means this is the proper way doing that:

```
var itemList = ArrayList<Item>()
```

You can also use

```
var itemList = mutableListOf<Item>()
```

which is exactly the same as using `ArrayList<Item>()` and should be used, since Kotlin may change the implementation later.

Comment: If you really want to use fixed indexes which is not recommended, you may want to use a HashMap over an ArrayList. A List is not designed to have fixed indexes except a LinkedList. Better use a HashMap and get rid of the outofboundexceptions

Comment: Not working in Android. Neither does the Hashmap technique works. It does not get updated. I need some other ideas.

Comment: I am trying to fill the GridView using the ArrayList.  Also tried the HashMap, does not update even a single value.